# ScrollTo doesn't scroll

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I ran into a curious problem: method `ScrollTo` doesn't work for the `ListView` inside root page initialized inside NavigationPage. The simple code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ListView listView;

    public MainPage()
    {


        var abs = new AbsoluteLayout { };            


        var src = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) { src.Add(i + 1 + " line"); }


        abs.Children.Add(listView = new ListView { ItemsSource = src }, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 0.9), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        abs.Children.Add(new Entry { BackgroundColor = Color.Gray }, new Rectangle(0, 1, 1, 0.1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

        Content = abs;

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var last = (listView.ItemsSource as List<string>).Last();
        listView.ScrollTo(last, ScrollToPosition.End, false);

    }


}
```

Here I try to scroll to the last element when the MainPage is loading. And that works fine if I has initialized App so:

```
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        MainPage = new App1.MainPage { Title = "Main" };
    }
```

But if I put the MainPage inside NavigationPage, scrolling does not occur:

```
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new App1.MainPage { Title = "Main" });
    }
```

What is the correct way to solve this?

PS: now I outflank this moment through `Device.StartTimer`, but I think this is wrong crutch

Comment: Put some delay and try.

Comment: You could invoke  `await listView.ScrollToAsync(last, ScrollToPosition.End, false);`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, as I know `ListView` has no `ScrollToAsync`  method. It has just `ScrollTo()`

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue, you could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .